# Create Value Array From Model into String in Swift

Tags: swift, multidimensional-array

I want to create data like 
[image]

From model like
[image]

but the data that I get is like this
[image]

how can i get the data structure like that (top)? clean there is no model name and no optional in data

Note: i use method create value like this

```
        for i in 0 ..< self.dataProduct.count {
        let id_sell = "\(self.dataProduct[i].seller_id ?? 0)"
        let origin = self.dataProduct[i].origin ?? 0
        let product = self.dataProduct[i].product ?? []

        var dataItem = [DataCheckoutMitras.ProductItemCheckout]()
        var itemMitra : DataCheckoutMitras?
        var dataCourierSelected : CourierObject?
        for x in 0 ..< product.count {
            var item : DataCheckoutMitras.ProductItemCheckout?

            item = DataCheckoutMitras.ProductItemCheckout(product_id: product[x].product_id ?? 0,
                                                          name: product[x].name ?? "",
                                                          price: product[x].price ?? 0,
                                                          subTotal: product[x].subTotal ?? 0,
                                                          quantity: product[x].quantity ?? 0,
                                                          weight: product[x].weight ?? 0,
                                                          origin_item: origin,
                                                          notes: product[x].notes ?? "")

            dataItem.append(item!)
        }

        for x in 0 ..< self.id_seller.count {
            if id_sell == self.id_seller[x] {
                dataCourierSelected = self.dataKurir[x]
            }
        }

        itemMitra = DataCheckoutMitras(origin: origin, select_price_courier: dataCourierSelected, items: dataItem)
        mitras.append(itemMitra!)
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you are facing is because you are printing definition of your struct. What you want is the JSON to do so you will need to:

1. Implement `Codable` protocol in both of your `struct`
   This also applied to your `CourierObject`

   ```swift
   struct DataCheckoutMitras: Codable {
       let origin: Int?
       let items: [ProductItemCheckout]?

       struct ProductItemCheckout: Codable {
           let product_id : Int?
           let name : String?
       }
   }
   ```
2. encode the struct to JSON data using `JSONEncoder`

   ```swift
   let encodedJSONData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(mitras)
   ```
3. convert JSON to string

   ```swift
   let jsonString = String(data: encodedJSONData, encoding: .utf8)
   print(jsonString)
   ```